# spring boot REST API not able to fetch response sometimes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

There is something strange happening. I have written a simple spring boot application rest api code (below). API is able to fetch response instantly. But everytime when I check later, it just halts. I tried both ways on postman and using curl on production environment. Don't know whats causing this.

code:

**rest controller**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
    @GetMapping(value="topContentByCtgId",consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler> topContentByCtgId( @RequestParam(value="ctgId",required=true)int ctgId){
        long l_time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<TopContent> list = topContentRepo.findByCategoryIdAndIsActive(ctgId,1);
        if(list!=null && list.size()!=0) {
            Collections.sort(list);
            long l_time_end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long l_diff = l_time_end-l_time_start;
            return new ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler>(new SuccessResponseBeanRefined(HttpStatus.OK, ResponseStatusEnum.SUCCESSFUL, ApplicationResponse.SUCCESSFUL, list,l_diff+" ms") ,HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        long l_time_end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long l_diff = l_time_end-l_time_start;
        return  new ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler>(new SuccessResponseBeanRefined(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ResponseStatusEnum.FAILED, ApplicationResponse.Failed," > Bad request",l_diff+" ms"),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

    }
```

**spring data jpa repository**

```
public interface TopContentRepository extends JpaRepository<TopContent, Integer>,TopContentRepositoryCustom{
List<TopContent> findByCategoryIdAndIsActive(int categoryId,int isActive);
}
```

It is not that I am not able to get response. I am getting response instantly, when I start my jar file. But after sometimes (say half an hour later) it gets stuck forever (may come up with response but almost taking 15 mins or so), until I restart jar file again on production. I see no connection lost, as I am able to see my other UI application running perfectly with no delays on very same server. Whats causing this. How can I debug it. I even tried using native query, but no success, same problem. First few times it runs perfectly then just takes too long. Any suggestions..

Comment: try create some sample endpoint without using db call check the problem still exist

Comment: yes good idea. checking

Comment: in addition to @deadshot, may be good to check if there is a dependency creating the issue.

Comment: @J.Doe Please collect the thread dump when you see response freezes. Your code may be right but it seems you are interacting with DB so may be something there to look at as well. Put some logging in your code to highlight in and out times.

Comment: actually issue is solved now. Thanks @deadshot .. I had this two layer architecture. UI was deployed in AWS and MySQL DB server was in some other network. Though it was working but only for an 1/2 hour or so. So I made a service layer jar deployment on one of that other network to interact with DB also available on same network. And that solved my problem.  I still not understand why it happened at first place i.e. interacting directly from AWS to some remote given IP where mysql resides

Comment: @J.Doe may be firewall issue or something